# Ошибка в коде: "Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения."

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

////////////автобусы в парке
class List_Park {
public:
    int buss_number;
    char driver_name[50];
    int road_number;

    List_Park *next;
    List_Park *prev;


        List_Park *pbeg;
        List_Park *pend;
        List_Park() { pbeg = 0; pend = 0; };
        void add(int buss_number, char driver_name[50], int road_number);
        List_Park *find(int buss_number);
        List_Park *insert(int buss_number, char driver_name[50], int road_number,int key);
        bool  remove(int buss_number);
        void print();
        ~List_Park();
};


void List_Park:: add(int buss_number, char driver_name[50], int road_number) {
    List_Park *pv = new List_Park;
    if (pbeg == 0) {

    pbeg = pend = pv; 
    pv->buss_number = buss_number;
    strcpy_s(pv->driver_name, driver_name);
    pv->road_number = road_number;
    }
    else {

        pv->buss_number = buss_number;
        strcpy_s(pv->driver_name, driver_name);
        pv->road_number = road_number;
        pv->next = 0;
        pv->prev = pend;
        pend->next = pv;
        pend = pv;
    }
}

List_Park *List_Park::find(int buss_number) {
    List_Park *pv = pbeg;
    while (pv) {
        if (pv->buss_number == buss_number)break;
        pv = pv->next;
    }
    return pv;
}

List_Park *List_Park::insert(int buss_number, char driver_name[50], int road_number, int key) {
    if (List_Park *pkey = find(key)) {
        List_Park *pv = new List_Park;
        pv->buss_number = buss_number;
        strcpy_s(pv->driver_name, driver_name);
        pv->road_number = road_number;

        pv->prev = pkey;
        pv->next = pkey->next;
        pkey->next = pv;

        if (pkey != pend) { pkey->next->prev = pv; }
        else pend = pv;
        return pv;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool List_Park::remove(int buss_number){
    if (List_Park *pkey = find(buss_number)) {
        if (pkey == pbeg) {
            pbeg = pbeg->next;
            pbeg->prev = 0;
        }
        else if (pkey == pend) {
            pend = pend->prev;
            pend->next = 0;
        }
        else {
            pkey->next->prev = pkey->prev;
            pkey->prev->next = pkey->next;
        }
        delete pkey;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void List_Park::print() {
    List_Park *pkey = pbeg;

    cout << "Автобусы что находятся в парке" << endl;

    while (pkey) {
        cout <<endl<<endl<< "Номер автобуса :" << pkey->buss_number << endl;
        OemToCharA(pkey->driver_name, pkey->driver_name);
        cout << "Имя и инициалы водителя :" <<pkey->driver_name << endl;
        cout << "Номер маршрута :" << pkey->road_number<<endl<<endl;

        cout << "Hi" << endl;
        pkey = pkey->next;
    }

}


List_Park::~List_Park() {
    if (pbeg != 0) {
        List_Park *pv = pbeg;
        while (pv) {
            pv = pv->next;
            delete pbeg;
            pbeg = pv;
        }
    }
}



////////////////автобусы что находятся на выезде
class run_busses {
public:
    int buss_number;
    char driver_name[50];
    int road_number;
    run_busses *next;
    run_busses *prev;

    run_busses *pbeg;
    run_busses *pend;

    run_busses() { pbeg = 0; pend = 0; }
    void add(int buss_number, char driver_name[50], int road_number);
    run_busses *find(int buss_number);
    run_busses *insert(int buss_number, char driver_name[50], int road_number,int key);
    bool remove(int key);
    void print();
    ~run_busses();
};



void run_busses:: add(int buss_number, char driver_name[50], int road_number) {
    run_busses *pv = new run_busses;
    if (pbeg == 0) { pbeg = pend = pv;
    pv->buss_number = buss_number;
    strcpy_s(pv->driver_name, driver_name);
    pv->road_number = road_number;
    }
    else {
        pv->buss_number = buss_number;
        strcpy_s(pv->driver_name,driver_name);
        pv->road_number = road_number;
        pv->next = 0;
        pend->next = pv;
        pv->prev = pend;
        pend = pv;
    }
}

 run_busses * run_busses::find(int buss_number) {
     run_busses *pv = pbeg;
     while (pv) {
         if (pv->buss_number = buss_number)break;
         pv = pv->next;
     }
     return pv;
}
 run_busses * run_busses::insert(int buss_number, char driver_name[50], int road_number,int key) {
     if(run_busses* pkey=find(key)){
     run_busses *pv = new run_busses;
     pv->buss_number = buss_number;
     strcpy_s(pv->driver_name, driver_name);
     pv->road_number = road_number;
     pkey->next = pv;
     pv->prev = pkey;
     pv->next = pkey->next;
     if (pkey != pend) { pkey->next->prev = pv; }
     else pend = pv;
     return pv;
     }
     return 0;
 }

 bool run_busses ::remove( int buss_number){
    if( run_busses *pv = find(buss_number)){
     if (pv == pbeg) {
         pbeg = pv->next;
         pbeg->prev = 0;
     }
     else if (pv == pend) {
         pend = pv->prev;
         pend->next = 0;
     }
     else {
         pv->next->prev = pv->prev;
         pv->prev->next = pv->next;
     }
     delete pv;
     return 1;
    }
    return 0;
 }



 void run_busses::print() {
     run_busses * pv = pbeg;
     cout <<endl <<"Автобусы в дороге" << endl;
     while (pv) {
         cout << "Автобус в дороге " << pv->buss_number << endl;
         OemToCharA(pv->driver_name, pv->driver_name);
         cout << "Имя и фамилия водителя " << pv->driver_name << endl;
         cout << "Номер маршрута" << pv->road_number << endl;
         pv = pv->next;
     }
 }

 run_busses ::~run_busses() {
     if (pbeg != 0) {
         run_busses *pv = pbeg;
         while (pv) {
             delete pv;
             pv = pv->next;
             pbeg = pv;
         }
     }
 }


 ///работа с автобусами
 class Lists_add {
     int buss_number;
     char driver_name[50];
     int road_number;
     int buss_count;
     int rand_road;
 public:
     void full_buss(List_Park *&L);
     void move_buss(List_Park *&L,run_busses *&R,List_Park *&pkey);
 };



 void Lists_add::full_buss(List_Park *&L) {
     cout << "Введите кол-во автобусов" << endl;
     cin >> buss_count;
     srand(time(0));
     rand_road = rand() % buss_count + 1;
     for (int i(0); i<buss_count; i++) {
         cout <<endl <<"Введите номер автобусса " << endl;
         cin >> buss_number;
         cout << "Введите имя водителя" << endl;
         cin >> driver_name;
        cout << "Введите номер маршрута" << endl;
         cin >> road_number;
         L->add(buss_number, driver_name, road_number);
     }

 }
 void Lists_add::move_buss(List_Park *&L,run_busses *&R,List_Park *&pkey) {
     cout << endl << "Сколько автобусов вы хотите отправить в дорогу?" << endl;
     cin >> buss_count;
     for(int i(0);i<buss_count;i++){
     cout <<endl <<"Какой автобус отправить в дорогу?" << endl;
     cin >> buss_number ;
     pkey = L->find(buss_number);
     cout << endl << pkey->buss_number << endl;
     cout << pkey->driver_name << endl;
     cout << pkey->road_number << endl;
     R->add(pkey->buss_number, pkey->driver_name, pkey->road_number);
     L->remove(buss_number);
     }
 }

void main() {

    setlocale(0, "rus");

    Lists_add *LA = new Lists_add;
    List_Park *LP = new List_Park;
    List_Park *pkey = new List_Park;
    run_busses *R = new run_busses;
    LA->full_buss(*&LP);
    LP->print();
    LA->move_buss(*&LP, *&R,*&pkey);
    LP->print();
    R->print();
    delete LP;
    delete LA;
    delete pkey;
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: А теперь берете отладчик и смотрите на какой именно строке оно происходит.

Comment: Вы не указали, ни в какой именно строке происходит сбой (а это очень просто - даже если не знаете, как работать с отладчиком, всегда можно вспомнить опыт предков и натыкать отладочный вывод типа `cout << __LINE__ << endl;`), ни при каких данных происходит сбой... Здесь - не команда тестировщиков :(

Answer (score 1):

Падение происходит в функции

```
bool List_Park::remove(int buss_number)
```

в строке

```
pbeg = pbeg->next;
```

потому что pbeg равно 0 (NULL). А такое нужно проверять.

Также  в коде замечено много утечек памяти и просто плохого кода. Например,

- `run_busses *R = new run_busses;` - а удалять кто будет?
- деструктор

  ```
  run_busses ::~run_busses() {
       if (pbeg != 0) {
           run_busses *pv = pbeg;
           while (pv) { // 
               delete pv;
               pv = pv->next; // обращаемся к удаленному объекту
               pbeg = pv;
           }
       }
   }
  ```
- `if (pv->buss_number = buss_number)break;` в функции `run_busses::find`. Там точно одно равно? Возможно, это и будет причина этого падения. Там ещё в одном месте есть подобное. Такой код конечно может быть, но очень сильно с душком.
- обилие strcpy_s и `char[50]`. Может просто std::string? c++ же в метках.
- `#include<conio.h>` ... просто не используйте.
- `main` должна возвращать int.
- `setlocale(0, "rus");` и `OemToCharA` - смените преподавателя или учебник.

Answer (score 0):

В функцию `move_buss` передается `pkey`, который NULL. Думаю так быть не должно.

Comment: run_busses ::~run_busses() {
  if (pbeg != 0) {
   run_busses *pv = pbeg;
   while (pv) {
    delete pv;
    pv = pv->next;
    pbeg = pv;
   }
  }
 }